# Approaches to grammar

Tags: grammar

Are the rules of *grammar* pretty much like the laws of, say *physics* or *mathematics*?

In *mathematics*, for example, a new area of research is necessitated because the known branches are inadequate in explaining a certain problem. Newton invented *calculus* because it dealt with a variety of problems more efficiently than did the then-known branches of mathematics.

Is it the same with grammar? Just to illustrate, I often notice here that whenever a question on *gerunds* or *participles* is asked, there are two schools of thought— one that deals separately with these two; and the other school, which clubs them together as *gerund-participles*. There is seldom a convergence of views unlike in physical sciences where different schools of thought ultimately arrive at the same general conclusion despite difference in approaches. Perhaps, this explains the *gerund vs participle* *treadmill*.

What difference does it make if we stick to the traditional approach (treating separately *gerunds* and *participles*, for example)?

I would highly appreciate your answers.

Comment: This is more the abstract to a research paper than a question.

Comment: Grammar is more like witchcraft than it is like science.

Comment: @user405662 It is hard to understand what you want. First of all, the title is not a question. In the body, there is text but no references (at least consider adding an example of the gerund-participle thing). Above all, your text lacks articulation. If you don't want to do any of this, consider starting a blog instead.

Comment: The answer is that they are not alike, despite any superficial similarities. The laws of physics are quantifiable descriptions of nature, testable against observation. They have predictive power. These two aspects, testable and predictive, distinguish them from grammatical laws which, as is often shown in this site, have only partial testability, are open to opinion despite the facts of observation, and lack predictive power. The question is interesting but not one for this site.

Comment: There is no reason to separate them. They are both verbs with the same function, i.e. heads of non-finite VPs. Some, by conversion, can be genuine nouns (aka 'gerundial nouns'), as in "I witnessed the **killing** of the seals", where "killing" is clearly a noun by virtue of the article "the" and the _of_ PP as complement. You should do some research on the modern trend of combining the two.

Comment: Thankyou; kind. I also wonder about mathematical “laws”. In my limited experience, mathematics progresses by proposition, followed by logical derivation to identify consequent  truths and to exclude possible untruths. The application of mathematics to the physical world is a mapping of concepts onto reality. The wonder is that it so often works! Grammatical laws are so modified by idiom, or sometimes refuted by idiom, that the mapping is much more obscure. I think you have uncovered a rich vein of discussion indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules of grammar don’t work like laws of Maths. Rules of Physics are slightly closer to rules of English ... in the way that jumping gets you closer to the moon.

English isn’t precise, and it isn’t consistent. You can make up rules that work in many situations, but you always have to watch out for exceptions. Here’s a classic example:

- time flies like an arrow
- planes fly like birds

Generalising, you might develop a rule that claims “X flies like Y” tells you how Y flies by comparing it to how X flies.

Then you come to:

- fruit flies like a banana

and the rule fails (because *flies* is part of the noun “fruit flies”, and “like” has the sense of “enjoy” rather than “comparison”).

So rules of English are merely descriptive of certain classes of words, phrases, and so on. In a way, this parallels the development of rules of Physics. People generated models from empirical observation. They didn’t always work, and when they did, they weren’t always precisely correct - compare Newtonian mechanics with models based on Relativity, for example.

The major difference is that English is significantly more malleable - just take a look at poetry. You can break rules of sentence structure, word order, etc, and still have a body of comprehensible text. So ‘rules’ of English will never be as rigorous as those of the mathematical sciences.

Answer (score 2):

So-called rules of grammar differ from rules of mathematics or physics because they depend on human behavior. Rules of grammar are descriptive of how people actually use language. It may be more useful to think of descriptive patterns.  Often patterns are described to help those learning a second language. The result may be entirely unfamiliar to native speakers, for example, the description of the order of adjectives before a noun.

This situation is different from, say, the identification of prime numbers. A number does not become more or less prime over time, but an English construction can become more or less common, or standard, over time; or its meaning may change.